# How to resolve error "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" in Storm Application while running in local cluster?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, nimbus

I am getting folowing error while running "real time feed processing with storm" application on local cluster. Link : http://www.datasalt.com/2012/01/real-time-feed-processing-with-storm/

```
4013 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Starting inprocess zookeeper at port 2000 and dir C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\/94df123c-dd99-473b-b98e-66fbf59dd37c
4828 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Starting Nimbus with conf {"dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\/a2319971-49a1-4767-a387-6ca302abc5de", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker.childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "topology.max.spout.pending" nil, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" [6700 6701 6702 6703], "topology.debug" false, "nimbus.task.launch.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 1, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.zmq", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m", "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topology.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
4843 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Using default scheduler
4999 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
5420 [main-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
5655 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
5970 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
6032 [main-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
6110 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
6110 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
6235 [main-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
6329 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
6391 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Starting Supervisor with conf {"dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\/d4fea730-5c16-4e20-a444-3769ee829406", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker.childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "topology.max.spout.pending" nil, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" (1 2 3), "topology.debug" false, "nimbus.task.launch.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 1, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.zmq", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m", "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topology.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
6454 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
6517 [main-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
6611 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
6798 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Starting supervisor with id 744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1 at host DS-7071BC86F1CB.HCLT.CORP.HCL.IN
6798 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Starting Supervisor with conf {"dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\/1116e43d-d550-484a-bf2e-d41968c48434", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker.childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "topology.max.spout.pending" nil, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" (4 5 6), "topology.debug" false, "nimbus.task.launch.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 1, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.zmq", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m", "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topology.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
6813 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
6923 [main-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
6985 [main] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
7172 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Starting supervisor with id 71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc at host DS-7071BC86F1CB.HCLT.CORP.HCL.IN
7266 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Received topology submission for feedcount with conf {"topology.max.task.parallelism" nil, "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.kryo.register" nil, "topology.kryo.decorators" (), "topology.name" "feedcount", "storm.id" "feedcount-1-1410328057", "topology.workers" 2, "topology.debug" true}
7364 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Activating feedcount: feedcount-1-1410328057
7588 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.scheduler.EvenScheduler - Available slots: (["71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc" 4] ["71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc" 5] ["71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc" 6] ["744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1" 1] ["744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1" 2] ["744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1" 3])
7651 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Setting new assignment for topology id feedcount-1-1410328057: #backtype.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\/a2319971-49a1-4767-a387-6ca302abc5de/nimbus/stormdist/feedcount-1-1410328057", :node->host {"744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1" "DS-7071BC86F1CB.HCLT.CORP.HCL.IN", "71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc" "DS-7071BC86F1CB.HCLT.CORP.HCL.IN"}, :executor->node+port {[3 3] ["71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc" 4], [6 6] ["744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1" 1], [5 5] ["71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc" 4], [4 4] ["744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1" 1], [2 2] ["744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1" 1], [1 1] ["71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc" 4]}, :executor->start-time-secs {[1 1] 1410328058, [5 5] 1410328058, [3 3] 1410328058, [2 2] 1410328058, [4 4] 1410328058, [6 6] 1410328058}}
7760 [Thread-5] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Downloading code for storm id feedcount-1-1410328057 from C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\/a2319971-49a1-4767-a387-6ca302abc5de/nimbus/stormdist/feedcount-1-1410328057
7981 [Thread-8] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Downloading code for storm id feedcount-1-1410328057 from C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\/a2319971-49a1-4767-a387-6ca302abc5de/nimbus/stormdist/feedcount-1-1410328057
8149 [Thread-5] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Finished downloading code for storm id feedcount-1-1410328057 from C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\/a2319971-49a1-4767-a387-6ca302abc5de/nimbus/stormdist/feedcount-1-1410328057
8232 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Launching worker with assignment #backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.LocalAssignment{:storm-id "feedcount-1-1410328057", :executors ([6 6] [4 4] [2 2])} for this supervisor 744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1 on port 1 with id 66168bde-c945-46b3-8276-76598a2b7d3a
8234 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Launching worker for feedcount-1-1410328057 on 744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1:1 with id 66168bde-c945-46b3-8276-76598a2b7d3a and conf {"dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\/d4fea730-5c16-4e20-a444-3769ee829406", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm",
```

................

```
9689 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Launching receive-thread for 744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1:1
9704 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker has topology config {"storm.id" "feedcount-1-1410328057", "dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\/d4fea730-5c16-4e20-a444-3769ee829406", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.kryo.decorators" (), "topology.name" "feedcount", "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker.childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "topology.max.spout.pending" nil, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" (1 2 3), "topology.debug" true, "nimbus.task.launch.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.kryo.register" nil, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 2, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.zmq", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m", "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topology.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
9718 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker 66168bde-c945-46b3-8276-76598a2b7d3a for storm feedcount-1-1410328057 on 744a08ba-16c2-4043-81d0-a2fc45071fe1:1 has finished loading
9711 [Thread-34-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt __system:(-1)
9710 [Thread-32] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
9757 [Thread-32] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Reporting start.
9757 [Thread-32] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Reporting finished.
9752 [Thread-34-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt __system:(-1)
9763 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor __acker:[1 1]
9764 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: __acker __system ["startup"]
9765 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks __acker:[1 1]
9766 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Timeouts disabled for executor __acker:[1 1]
9767 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor __acker:[1 1]
9767 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Launching receive-thread for 71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc:4
9772 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker has topology config {"storm.id" "feedcount-1-1410328057", "dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\/1116e43d-d550-484a-bf2e-d41968c48434", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.kryo.decorators" (), "topology.name" "feedcount", "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker.childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "topology.max.spout.pending" nil, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" (4 5 6), "topology.debug" true, "nimbus.task.launch.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.kryo.register" nil, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 2, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.zmq", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m", "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topology.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
9772 [Thread-9] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker d01f3c23-f1c9-4fad-b5b2-540e932f98a8 for storm feedcount-1-1410328057 on 71fe3715-ba8e-40f2-a64b-cc00e46370bc:4 has finished loading
9801 [Thread-38-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt __acker:(1)
9801 [Thread-38-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt __acker:(1)
9805 [Thread-21-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Processing received message source: feedSpout:3, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [1491166814217847811, -3901990751820783443, 3]
10757 [Thread-32] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Reporting start.
10776 [Thread-32] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Reporting finished.
**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**
11065 [Thread-27-fetcherBolt] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: fetcherBolt __ack_fail [1491166814217847811]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at org.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:150)
    at org.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:87)
    at datasalt.storm.feeds.FetcherBolt.execute(FetcherBolt.java:62)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3498$tuple_action_fn__3500.invoke(executor.clj:615)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__3421.invoke(executor.clj:383)
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__2962.onEvent(disruptor.clj:43)
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:82)
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:61)
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:62)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3498$fn__3510$fn__3557.invoke(executor.clj:730)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__444.invoke(util.clj:403)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
11068 [Thread-21-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Processing received message source: fetcherBolt:5, stream: __ack_fail, id: {}, [1491166814217847811]
11068 [Thread-21-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting direct: 3; __acker __ack_fail [1491166814217847811]
```

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` is the result of a client trying to connect to some service at a certain IP-address and port and can't reach it. Likely causes are that there is a configuration error (you are not trying to connect to the service you thought you did), the service is not where the client thinks it is or that something along the way is blocking the connection attempts (firewalls, need for proxy configuration).

Comment: How are you running the topology? Can you share the command which you use to start the topology?

Comment: @John I am running topology within a Java Application in eclipse. 
  LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
  cluster.submitTopology("feedcount", conf,
    builder.createTopology());

Comment: @DanielBarbarian I am running topology within a Java Application in eclipse. On running the application it starts inprocess Zookepper at port 2000. I think this is creating the problem but i don't know how to resolve it. :(

Comment: At least that means you know at what port you should try to get the service. If the client tries to find the service elsewhere there should be a configuration of some kind. Unfortunately I don't know enough about this setup to help you further.

Comment: Can you try cleaning you temp directory 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\' and try running again ?